# Why can't I override a val with a case object of a matching type?

Tags: scala

Given:

```
trait Mixin {}

case class A(a: Int) extends Mixin
case object B extends Mixin

trait Base {
  val m = A(1)
}

trait Sub extends Base {
  override val m = B // does. not. compute.
}
```

I get a compilation error in trait `Sub`:

```
<console>:18: error: overriding value m in trait Base of type A;
 value m has incompatible type
         override val m = B // does. not. compute.
                      ^
```

Why? The case object inherits the correct trait, just like the case class does. This is Scala 2.10.

Comment: Might I suggest that you declare `Base.m` as a `def` and not a `val`.  Having overridden vals in traits can lead to all sorts of initialization-order woes.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make `m` of type `Mixin`:

```
 trait Base {
    val m: Mixin = A(1)
 }
```

Comment: As often, I just figured out my stupidity the minute after I posted the question. Thanks. :)

Comment: I thought the question was going to be `trait Sub extends Base { override case object m extends Mixin }`